# System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of Map

Tags: apex, integration, json, callout

I'm returning one JSON response from the rest API from another Salesforce instance. while deserialising JSON I'm getting **System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of Map**

Returning Map code:

```
Map<Id,Boolean> activeAccPerIdMap = new Map<Id,Boolean>();
string activeAccPerIdMapJSON = JSON.serializePretty(activeAccPerIdMap);
return activeAccPerIdMapJSON;
```

In the instance from where it is called:

```
system.debug('>>> RESPONSE_BODY... '+res1.getbody());
        
string jsonBody = res1.getbody();
system.debug('>>> jsonBody...'+JSON.deserialize(jsonBody,Map<string,Boolean>.class));
```

I'm receiving the returned value in this form: `{\n  \"0012O00000E5MSOQA3\" : false\n}`

How can I deserialize the Map in my method from where I'm calling

Comment: What is the actual value of the JSON body you are receiving?

Comment: I'm getting value in this form: {\n  \"0012O00000E5MSOQA3\" : false\n}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have an extra level of encoding. The valid JSON would be:

```
{
    "0012O00000E5MSOQA3": false
}
```

Note the lack of a backslashes escaping the double quotes. But if that goes through a second serialize the result will just be a string (with the quotes escaped).

A common cause of this double serialization is to serialize yourself in a method body and then return that JSON string via a method that automatically serializes. For that case, return the `Map` from the method and let the platform do the serialization.

**PS**

For some reason that I don't know returning `Map<Id, String>` from a `@HttpPost` method is not supported. Making that map `Map<String, String>` instead works around that.

Comment: When I try to return the Map from the method, I'm getting this error HttpPost methods do not support return type of Map<Id,Boolean>

Comment: @sfdc See the PS.